# Idiomatic io-streams directory traversal

Tags: haskell, haskell-snap-framework, conduit

I was [discussing some code on Reddit](http://www.reddit.com/r/haskell/comments/24t0sj/foldablemapm_maybe_and_recursive_functions_school/chblpp7), and it made me curious about how this would be implemented in io-streams. Consider the following code which traverses a directory structure and prints out all of the filenames:

```
import           Control.Exception         (bracket)
import qualified Data.Foldable             as F
import           Data.Streaming.Filesystem (closeDirStream, openDirStream,
                                            readDirStream)
import           System.Environment        (getArgs)
import           System.FilePath           ((</>))

printFiles :: FilePath -> IO ()
printFiles dir = bracket
    (openDirStream dir)
    closeDirStream
    loop
  where
    loop ds = do
        mfp <- readDirStream ds
        F.forM_ mfp $ \fp' -> do
            let fp = dir </> fp'
            ftype <- getFileType fp
            case ftype of
                FTFile -> putStrLn fp
                FTFileSym -> putStrLn fp
                FTDirectory -> printFiles fp
                _ -> return ()
            loop ds

main :: IO ()
main = getArgs >>= mapM_ printFiles
```

Instead of simply printing the files, suppose we wanted to create some kind of streaming filepath representation. I know how this would work in enumerator, conduit, and pipes. However, since the intermediate steps require acquisition of a scarce resource (the `DirStream`), I'm not sure what the implementation would be for io-streams. Can someone provide an example of how that would be done?

For comparison, [here's the conduit implementation](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/conduit-extra-1.1.0.3/docs/src/Data-Conduit-Filesystem.html), which is made possible via `bracketP` and `MonadResource`. And here's how the conduit code would be used to implemented the same file printing program as above:

```
import           Control.Monad.IO.Class       (liftIO)
import           Control.Monad.Trans.Resource (runResourceT)
import           Data.Conduit                 (($$))
import           Data.Conduit.Filesystem      (sourceDirectoryDeep)
import qualified Data.Conduit.List            as CL
import           System.Environment           (getArgs)

main :: IO ()
main =
    getArgs >>= runResourceT . mapM_ eachRoot
  where
    -- False means don't traverse dir symlinks
    eachRoot root = sourceDirectoryDeep False root
                 $$ CL.mapM_ (liftIO . putStrLn)
```

Comment: Side comment: I was going to tag this with io-streams, but apparently SO thinks that conflicts with the existing iostreams tag. I put snap-framework on this instead, but if there's a better tag for io-streams questions, please let me know.

Comment: I hope it's a small directory structure; that looks painfully slow.  On my system, running `sourceDirectoryDeep` on a ghc build tree (without printing any output) takes about 1.6s, compared to 95ms when using `traverseDirectory` from posix-paths.

Comment: I'm not surprised it's slower; it's using `FilePath` instead of `RawFilePath`. There are also some missing rewrite rules for `sourceDirectoryDeep` right now, which might be a contributing factor. I'd be curious what the difference in speed is between posix-paths and streaming-commons itself, though.

Comment: posix-paths doesn't stat anything, which is probably the most substantial savings (after `RawFilePath`)

Comment: Ahh, that would do it. It's too bad `unix` doesn't expose more information with `readDirStream`, perhaps I should modify streaming-commons to expose more of the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typical style would be to do something like this:

```
traverseDirectory :: RawFilePath -> (InputStream RawFilePath -> IO a) -> IO a
```

i.e. a standard "with-" function, with the obvious implementation.

*Edit*: added a working example implementation: https://gist.github.com/gregorycollins/00c51e7e33cf1f9c8cc0

It's not exactly complicated but it's also not as trivial as I had first suggested.

Comment: Can you actually provide an implementation in terms of streaming-commons (or any other library you like)? I don't see how to get the proper resource allocation semantics given the recursive nature of traversal.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I added a comment on the Gist with some concerns about exception safety in the deallocation code.